# Why does Rust core library not provide `round`, `floor`, or `ceil` method for `f32`/`f64` type?

Tags: rust

Rust `core` library is a minimum base library that is designed to be platform agnostic. The `std` library in turn contains some platform specific things.

For converting floating point numbers to integers, specifically `round`, `floor` and `ceil`, they do not seem to have any platform relevance, but is only provided in `std` rather than `core`.

Is there any reason that these methods cannot be provided in `core`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because they depend on `libm` and thus were removed from `core` in [this PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27823)

Comment: Is this still true? I thought `floor` was implemented via intrinsics?

Comment: @JorgeLeitao I don't see why that would change anything, yes it's still true that they are not in `std` because they depend on `libm` (through the intrinsics)

Comment: Ahh, I did not know the dependency was `libm <- intrinsicts`. Thanks!